# What is wrong with my form post to a WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the Web API action I'm trying to call:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
[System.Web.Http.Route("Register")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

And this is the form I post to it with, in a sister project for the UI:

```
<form action="http://localhost:53231/api/Account/Register" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
</form>
```

When I try and submit the form, I get the following error in an XML response:

```
<ExceptionMessage>
    The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
```

A breakpoint on the first line of the API action is never even hit. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the model I'm expecting:

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does `RegisterBindingModel` contain only those 3 properties?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I've added that model to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are seeing is a general exception, which can be caused by any number of factors.

But I think you have circular referencing error. In order to solve it,
put the following lines at the top of your `Application_Start` method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

In this case it forced only JSON to be returned.

Comment: I'll try, but why would I have a reference loop with only three strings? I like the part about removing the XML formatter though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ProxyCreationEnabled to false in your Model Context

`Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

my example:

```
public partial class EventsEntities : DbContext
{
    public EventsEntities()
       : base("name=EventsEntities")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```